# spring boot embedded tomcat append log to every tomcat request

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-web

I am using spring boot version 1.3.3.  With the embedded tomcat.

For each web requests I would like to know how intercept a web request and do some custom code then continue on with the request.

My hunch is that I would override some default servlet bean or method?  I don't know much about this.

So to make the question specific.  For every web request how would I do the following code

```
@Override  
public void someGenericWebParentRequest(Servlet servletRequest){
   log.info("custom log called");
   MDC.put("host-name", System.getenv("HOSTNAME"));  // kibana hostname filter added

   // whatever code you fancy etc :-)       

   return servletRequest;  // continues onto web target controller 
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use **Servlet Filter** and add intercept requests in **doFilter().**
To add it into Spring Context, add **@Component.**

Refer this sample.

```
@Component
public class SecurityFilter implements Filter{
    @Override
    public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException {

    }

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
         //you can intercept request and response here
        System.out.println("###### security filter ");
        chain.doFilter(request, response);
    }

    @Override
    public void destroy() {

    }
}
```

Comment: this works thanks.  accepted the answer.  I have taken a look around on the filter is this like a kind of firewall for http requests into the spring app?

Comment: Yes, kind of, but http requests to Servlet ( not only spring app), please remember In spring there is default servlet called dispatcherservlet